# odd extension function and Dirichlet problem

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, fourier-series

so I need to find the odd extension function for :

$\phi (x) = \begin{cases}x& \text{ , } 0 \leq  x\leq 1   \\ 1& \text{ , }  1 \leq  x\leq 2\\ 3-x& \text{ , } 2\leq  x\leq 3 \end{cases}$

I'll use this : $f_{odd}(x)=\begin{cases}
 -f(-x)&  , -3\leq x <0\\ 
 f(x)&, 0\leq x \leq 3
\end{cases}$

So , where I need help is more here:

For the Fourier serie , I haven't be able to find it even using the Fourier Sine Series that I have to use in this limit value problem :

$\begin{cases}u_{tt} =c^{2}u_{xx}& , t>0\;, x\;\epsilon\; (0,3) \\ u(0,t)=u(3,t)=0 &  \\  u(x,0)=\phi (x)& ,x\;\epsilon\;[0,3]  \\ u_{t}(x,0)=0 & \  \end{cases}$

I really don't know at all how to do the last problem .. If anyone could help , thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean $x\in (0,3)$ on the equation $u_{tt} = c^2u_{xx}$?

Comment: Yes , sorry let met edit.

Comment: It is difficult to understand what exactly is the problem because there is a mix of  equations which one cannot say if they are or not original specifications of the problem. Would you mind edit separately first the original wording and secondly your thoughts and/or calculus.